# Generic method, RESTful app

Tags: java, generics, rest

I'm using RESTful application in my java project. Normally in my unit test classes, I use methods like this:

```
public Employee getEmployeeByEmail(String email) {
    ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource.path(beginPath + "getByEmail/" + email).get(
            ClientResponse.class);

    Employee employee = null;
    if (200 == clientResponse.getStatus()) {
        employee = clientResponse.getEntity(Employee.class);
    }

    return employee;
}
```

... but I have to use similar methods in almost 12 different classes. This is what I decided to do:

```
public class TestManager<T> {

private WebResource webResource;
private String beginPath;
private Class<T> clazz;

public TestManager(WebResource webResource, String beginPath, Class<T> clazz) {
    this.webResource = webResource;
    this.beginPath = beginPath;
    this.clazz = clazz;
}

public boolean objectExists(String methodPath, String uniqueFieldName, String uniqueField) {
    boolean check = false;
    ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource.path(beginPath + methodPath + "/" + uniqueField).get(
                ClientResponse.class);
    JSONObject jsonObject = clientResponse.getEntity(JSONObject.class);

    if (200 == clientResponse.getStatus() && !jsonObject.isNull(uniqueFieldName)) {
        check = true;
    }

    return check;
}

public T getObjectById(String methodPath, long id) {
    ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource.path(beginPath + methodPath + "/" + id).get(
            ClientResponse.class);
    T object = null;
    if (200 == clientResponse.getStatus() && !clientResponse.getEntity(JSONObject.class).isNull("id")) {
        object = clientResponse.getEntity(clazz);
    }

    return object;
}
```

}

The method objectExists() works fine, but getObjectById() method generate stack trace:

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Error creating JSON-based XMLStreamReader - with linked exception:[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.io.IOException: stream is closed]
```

It seems that I can't do this:

```
object = clientResponse.getEntity(clazz);
```

But I have no idea how to fix it. Sorry for my english :P

Edit:
Im using jersey

Edit2:
**Solution**:
The problem was I used getEntity() method twice ... If I use it only once ... it works ... damn it

Answer (score 0):

It is a GET call. try calling it from  a browser.

If that gives the same error, then there is nothing wrong with your client.

Comment: Calling from a browser works fine, restful methods are OK. But I need unit tests which work when I do it normal way (like first code example), but don't work when I try clientResponse.getEntity(clazz);. There is a problem with generic types I think ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're having issues just with unit testing, then you might want to take a look at the Jersey Test Framework. [Here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/test-framework.html)'s a link to the jersey docs on it, google can point you to further tutorials.